# What should I do to buy small amount of shares?

Tags: united-states, stocks, shares

Let's assume the following scenario:

I have 5000$ which I am willing to invest(lose). I selected 5 public companies that I would like to buy shares. Is there a way for me (an immigrant who works in US) to buy the shares of these companies for a close to current price (by this I mean that if currently the [price for a Microsoft share](https://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:MSFT) is 52.06$, I would pay close to this number per share and not 30% more).

If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just open an account with an online broker, of which there are many. You should expect to pay commission of about $5 to $10 per trade, and there will always be a bit of a split between bid and offer prices, but nothing remotely like 30%.

Comment: So basically if I will go and buy at the same time 10 share from company A, 20 from B and 50 from C (in total for 5000$) I will pay approximately <20$ as a commission?

Comment: Yes, somewhere between $15 and $30 for three trades. There may also be an annual fee or something similar, depending on the broker.

Comment: @random If you're trying to buy several stocks at once, Motif is great for that - they charge you only $10 to buy any number of stocks (up to 30) in a single transaction, in any weight you want.

Answer (score 3):

[Robinhood](https://www.robinhood.com/).  It uses your smart phone.  No fees at all.